# Gronwall Inequality And Contraction Maps

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm attempting to answer the homework question below and hit a snag (question in Italics, my work below)

[image: Contraction Mapping Proof_1]

(1) Is this accurate so far? AND

(2) How do I proceed next?  I feel like I need to use Gronwall's inequality but am having trouble applying the form.

We were given a hint that we need to get a metric out of this:

$d(f,g)=max${ $|f-g|e^{L(t- \tau)}$ }

I can see how the metric is related to Gronwall's inequality, but I don't see how to get there, and I don't see how to prove that our mapping T is Lipschitz with constant 0 $\le$ L $\lt$1.

Please keep the response a little generic as I need to do this.

Comment: missing metric information.

Comment: Sorry what metric information are you looking for? @runaround

Comment: How to measure the distance between two functions? Or what metric space is question raised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the correct metric modification, $d(f,g)=\max(|f(t)-g(t)|·e^{-L|t-\tau|})$
Now insert 
$$
|\phi(t)-\psi(t)|\le d(\phi,\psi)·e^{L|t-\tau|}
$$
to get non-expansion. 
It probably works better to prove contraction if the metric modification is a tad  more radical,
$$
d(f,g)=\max(|f(t)-g(t)|·e^{-2L|t-\tau|})
$$

---

Then
$$
|T(\phi)(t)-T(\psi)(t)|\le\int_τ^t L·d(\phi,\psi)·e^{2L|s-\tau|}ds
=\frac12(e^{2L|t-\tau|}-1)·d(\phi,\psi)
$$
so that finally
$$
d(T(\phi),T(\psi))\le \frac12·d(\phi,\psi)
$$

Comment: How did you know to use that metric modification? And where are you inserting  $|\phi - \psi|$? Do I need Gronwall's inequality anywhere?

Comment: Learned it at university. -- Into the inequality for the contraction constant. -- No, since it is not the same functions on the left and right.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know of a good place to read up on metric modifications?  I feel like I'm still not grasping the importance of the technique.